# iframe load and fallback

Tags: javascript, iframe, external

I have used several javascripts to put a loading message on my iframe but I can't get them to stick if there is no connection.

I sourcing an external site through an iframe.  I would like people to see a picture while it loads and then continue to see that picture until the load is complete.  Meaning that if the netork is down for that external site they will just continue seeing the picture.  I have the ability to add files/script on the external site if need be.  I just have loading scripts, does anyone know how I can keep the image up until we are sure there is connectivity to the external site?

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
<img onload="if (this.src.indexOf('http')!=-1) window.open(URL,iframename)" 
onerror="this.src='sitedown.gif'" 
src="http://foreignsite.com/siteup.gif"/>
```

Where sitedown.gif is a local file and the src is an image file from the remote site
This file can be a server process as long as it returns a valid image with a mime of image/xxx where xxx is jpg, gif, png or any other image type the browser understands.

Comment: You miss http:// and an image from that server!!! The image on error MUST be local and relative path

Comment: It is the full path to a picture... This editor is truncating things... You can see the whole path if you hover over it.

Comment: Ok. The on error needs to use a local image anyway. If the server is down you cannot load an image from it and the url must point to an image

Comment: So what does the console say? In ie and chrome it is built in, in Firefox download firebug. In all cases press f12 to see any errors

Comment: FF shows no errors at all.  In FF the script causes the exact same page to open in another tab though - which is bad.  In IE it shows Script87: Invalid Argument for the line above your script... no idea why the IE debugger is giving the line above yours (which is just beginning a table) the error but I guess somewhere in the js there is an invalid argument.  Usually can fix these myself but the error is too nondescript.

Comment: Sorry please name the iframe and change iframename argument to 'nameofyouriframe' replacing nameofyouriframe with the actual name (no spaces) you gave it